# Are there any repercussions to killing Policemen?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

If I kill all the policemen in the police station with the alarm activated will it prevent me from continuing the game?

What about other repercussions?

Comment: I don't agree with the reopen votes. This question is simply a subset of the duplicate whose answer emcompasses the answer for this question. It is a good question however.

Comment: @deutschZuid - Where does it mention policemen in the other answer? It just says you won't get some Pacifism achievements for killing civilians. The question even specifically states "without police finding out". If anything, the answer there is a subset of the answers here.

Comment: @Robotnik The *title* says 'the innocent'. So you are saying the police do not belong in that category?

Comment: @deutschZuid - Depends what side of the fence you sit on I suppose. I've never considered police "civilians" which is why I brought it up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope.

There are also no real repercussions. More info is [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/944090-deus-ex-human-revolution/60122045)

> Some cops might try to shoot you when you leave, but other than that
>   pretty much all you'll see is a newspaper that talks about a massacre
>   at the police station and some people will bring it up in
>   conversation.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, but certain achievements/trophies (`Pacifist` and `Foxiest of the Hounds` because of the alarm I believe) won't be available to be unlocked.